# How can I spell check an entire buffer?

Tags: spell-checking

Is there a built-in command or plugin available to trigger spell checking over the entire current buffer, prompting me for each word it detects to either ignore, add to dictionary, or correct spelling?

I've been using `]s` to skip through spelling suggestions and `zg` or `z=` to add to dictionary or suggest corrections, but when a buffer as a lot of instances of the same spelling it's kind of annoying skipping past every instance, especially when it's code or config files that have a lot of things that aren't misspelled but don't belong in the dictionary, like variable names or command line gibberish.

Comment: I've been happy with Ingo Karkat's SpellCheck.vim plugin, available at https://github.com/vim-scripts/SpellCheck and normally at http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=3844, except that vim.org is down at the moment.

Comment: You could add the words you want to skip to the `internal-wordlist`, with `zG`. Since the list is lost when you exit Vim, it's similar to 'skip', and Vim won't ask you again to correct the same word, in the same session. Another way would be to teach Vim to only spell-check by syntax, i.e. in *certain* regions, and ignore the others.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [LanguageTool](https://github.com/vim-scripts/LanguageTool) plugin to add a double functionality, it provides not only spell check but also grammar check using the external java tool. It checks the entire buffer and displays an error list buffer at the bottom. I find it quite useful.

I hope this helps.